# Image link to homepage is not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have a logo on the top left of my website which links to the home page. Some areas of the image aren't clickable. The areas that can be clicked work fine. The clickable/non-clickable areas seem to be dispersed randomly. How can I make the link work across the entire area of the logo?

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <a id="nav-logo" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo-header.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>
    </nav>
</header>

#nav-logo,
nav img{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Should work. Add: `border: 1px solid #f00;` and see where the image appears on the page.

Comment: Find a spot that isn't clickable and inspect that element, you most likely have an element positioned over it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#nav-logo { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's the `margin` which isn't clickable. Also, you are using the same CSS settings for the link AND the image, which doesn't really make sense (both floated *and*  inline-blocks, both have a margin etc.). Make the image `display: block`, define a width for the container, make the image width 100% and its height `auto`